# Can I map an EF entity to two tables with a polymorphic foreign key?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, polymorphic-associations, edmx

I would like to make a new, mapped entity that looks like this:

```
public class PathedItem
{
  public long Id { get; set; }      // from the Items table
  public string Name { get; set; }  // from the Items table
  public string Path { get; set; }  // from the Paths table
}
```

The problem is that `Path` is in a different table than the other items and one of those tables has a polymorphic foreign key.  Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Items (
  [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE Paths (
  [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Path] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
  [ItemId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
  [ItemType] [int] NOT NULL)
```

Microsoft has HOWTOs on mapping entities to two tables ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716698.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896233.aspx)), but they seem to rely on a normal foreign key.

Is there some way to map `Paths.ItemId` to `Items.Id` and then hardcode a value for `Paths.ItemType` in the join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create a view, with the columns that you require and a filter on the ItemType.

Then add that view to your entity model.